# How to launch Fleet instance with Boto2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, aws-sdk

There are now Spot Fleet instances, wondering how can we launch them / retrieve them with boto 2 ?

Could not find any details in Boto documentation.

Because when we create a Single instance in AWS, it creates a Fleet instead of Single Instance.

Answer (score 0):

Spot Fleet is not available with `boto` version 2. It is [unlikely to be added](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3489) to that version.

Instead, use [`request_spot_fleet()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=spot%20fleet#EC2.Client.request_spot_fleet) in `boto3`.

Comment: Can we mix Boto3 code with Boto2 code in same script ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Boto 3 functions have a library named `boto3`, whereas Boto 2 uses the `boto` prefix. You might have problems passing data *between* the functions, but you can certainly call functions from each library separately. These days, it's worth moving to `boto3`.

Comment: boto2 API is much leaner, cleaner, intuitive to use. Boto3 is really a pain. Can you try to make it Boto3 interface as clean as Boto2 ?

Comment: It's an open-source project. Feel free to contribute! https://github.com/aws/aws-cli